# cacheAsBitmap causing graphical glitch on GPU rendering mode in Adobe Air, when app runs on Dell Venue 8 7840

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, gpu

(if you'd like, [download a .zip of the source code](http://junk.mattlohkamp.com/adobe%20air%20gpu%20render%20cacheasbitmap.zip) that demonstrates the error.)

Start off with a new Adobe Air Android app, set to GPU rendering mode. Add a `DisplayObject` to the stage, and set its `.cacheAsBitmap` value to `true`. Then run the app on a Dell Venue 8 7840. Here's a screenshot: the green square is a simple `MovieClip` with the shape drawn using its . `.graphics` property. The glitched out space is supposed to be a red square, drawn using exactly the same method, only with `.cacheAsBitmap = true`

[image]

This only happens on this particular device, using this particular rendering mode - updating the Android OS version from 4.4 to 5.0 doesn't fix it.

Any ideas on what's causing this, and how to fix it without using a different rendering mode or not caching the graphics as bitmaps?

Comment: Maybe report a bug to Dell regarding this issue? It can as well be a hardware/driver error that you cannot resolve on your own.

Comment: I suggest you to try different AIR SDK versions (start from latest 16, 17 and 18 beta, you can download them here https://helpx.adobe.com/air/kb/archived-air-sdk-version.html), if bug exists in all versions report to adobe https://bugbase.adobe.com/. That device has intel atom platform, bug can be related to x86 support as well.

Comment: definitely only happens on this device - my friend's phone (non-intel chip, android 5.0.2) doesn't show the same glitch. only happens on this particular tablet.

Comment: publishing for different AIR SDK versions doesn't help - older *or* newer. We've been using v16 up until this point, incidentally.

Comment: I am seeing the exact same issue on Amazon Fire HD 7 (4th generation) tablet.

Comment: Same problem an Asus Zenfone. Quality to LOW solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had these unexpected results before, twisted them sometimes adding to cacheAsBitmap also cacheAsBitmapMatrix with a scaled 2x matrix. Takes more memory but did the trick a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
stage.quality = StageQuality.LOW;
```

This solved the issue for me.